# Using custom ListView Adapter not filling views outside screen

Tags: android, listview, findviewbyid, listview-adapter

I'm using different templates in a listview that is filled from an array through a custom adapter.
I'm adding items to a List 'items', depending on the position in the Listview a different template is used.

I have two issues, who are related, since my methods don't return the right View ID:

If I use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); the text in textviews is not adapted, but also the rows outside of the visible screen are not set/adapted. I use the following method to get the View ID:

```
TextView getText() {

        if (title == null) {

            switch (templateId) {

            case ListViewAdapter.TPL_TITLE:

                title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titletitle);

                break;

            case ListViewAdapter.TPL_PAYMENT:

             title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.titlepayment);

                break;

            }

        }

        return (title);

    }
```

In my activity I have different ListItems (a separate class):

```
items.add(new ListItem(id, title, description, amount, date, template));
```

I fill the list:

```
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, items);

        mainMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        mainMenu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have this getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        templateId=getTemplateID(items.get(position).getType());

        View row = convertView;

        ListViewWrapper wrapper = null;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewtemplates, null);

            wrapper = new ListViewWrapper(row);

            row.setTag(wrapper);

        } else {

            wrapper = (ListViewWrapper) row.getTag();
        }

        wrapper.setTemplateId(templateId);

        wrapper.populateFrom(items.get(position));

        return (row);

    }
```

In the wrapper:

```
 public void populateFrom(ListItem r) {

            getText().setText(r.getTitle()); 


            if (templateId == ListViewAdapter.TPL_TITLE) {

            }

            if (templateId == ListViewAdapter.TPL_PAYMENT) {
                 getSubtext().setText(r.getDescription());
                 getAmount().setText(r.getAmount());
                 getDate().setText(r.getDate());
                         }            }

            setTemplate();

        }
```

Hopefully this is readable and does anyone understand/recognize my issue. I guess the real question is, how do I get the right ViewID returned per row?

Comment: your view on how listviews work is not correct. A listview reuses view objects and doesnt make a new view object for each row. So an ViewID is not really usefull to work with because its not relevant to your collection of data

Comment: addition to user1281750 comment ... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that  if (title == null) {...} does not work, removing that solved the issue